# Sed an entire line with only the begin of the line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a config file with this line:

```
foo.bar = http://localhost/foo
```

I want to replace this line with a new url. For example:

```
foo.bar = http://new_url/bar
```

But I don't know the original url, I only know the name of the parameter.

I tried this:

```
sed "s!^foo.bar.*!foo.bar = http://new_url/bar!" test.ini
```

But it return an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` double-quotes and `!` don't go well when placed inside ( see `HISTORY EXPANSION` in `man bash`), change the separator to `@` (or) use single-quotes

```
sed 's@foo.bar.*@foo.bar = http://new_url/bar@' file
foo.bar = http://new_url/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *single* quotes to prevent shell expansion:

```
sed -e 's!^foo.bar.*!foo.bar = http://new_url/bar!'
```